# OpenCV execution speed (for loops and meanStdDev)

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, opencv, for-loop

I'm fairly new to OpenCV and C++ ( learning it now after doing a fair share if image processing on MATLAB and LabView).

I'm having a weird issue I wanted to ask your opinion.
I'm trying to do a fairly simple thing: moving window 1x9 stdev on a gray scaled image (~ 4500X2000 pix).

here is the heart of the code:

```
    Mat src = imread("E:\\moon project\\Photos\\Skyline testing\\IMGP6043 sourse.jpg");
    Scalar roi_mean, roi_stdev;
    Mat stdev_map(src.rows, src.cols, CV_64FC1,Scalar(0));
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int t = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < src_gray.cols - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < src_gray.rows - 8; j++)
    {           
        meanStdDev(src_gray.col(i).rowRange(j,j+9), roi_mean, roi_stdev);
        stdev_map.at<double>(j, i) = roi_stdev[0];
    }
}
t = clock() - t;
cout << "stdev calc : " << t << " msec" << endl;
```

Now on the aforementioned image it takes 35 seconds to run the double loop (delta t value) and even if I throw away the meanStdDev and just assign a constant to stdev_map.at(j, i) it still takes 14 seconds to run the double loop.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong since on Labview it takes only 2.5 seconds to chew this baby with the exact same math.

Please help me.

Comment: If you compile in opencv debug mode, stdev_map.at<double>(j, i) might be quit slow beacuse it does range checking

Comment: for starters, you're doing a copy of the column (col(i)) in the most inner loop over rows (that is, for every pixel)

Comment: @berak, no, it does not copy matrix data only its header : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-col

Comment: still wrong place  to do it

Comment: yep, but I think the problem is at(), as he said if he removes the    meanStdDev call still execution is 14 seconds

Comment: how else can i access stdev_map value by value?
and is there faster way to access Mat type submatrix?

Comment: You can try instead of src_gray.col(i).rowRange(j,j+9) something like src_gray(Rect(i, j, 9, 9)) but I am not sure if it helps. Definitely, what about debug mode, do you use opencv libaries in debug or release?

Comment: Try to use the latest version of opencv which uses `parallel_for` inside the library functions to make execution faster. Matlab & Labview use par loop to make it faster. which version of opencv are you using?

Comment: I use debug libraries. Can the execution differences be so big between the two (few times)?
I use openCV 2.4.9
Regarding MATALB: interestingly enough matlab takes forever to complete this task ( i stopped it after two minutes ), which tbh was expected since he handles for loops poorly. Labview is teh only one to shine in this regard.

Comment: "I use debug libraries" - oh, that sure makes a huge difference with at() and friends, as there's range checks in debug mode, but not in release.

Comment: @JeniaM if your code in matlab is the same as this one, with 2 for loops, no wonder it takes ages

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question and some of the comments: do compile the lib in release mode will surely increase the computation time, by what order it depends, for example if you are using eigen it probably will speed things up a lot.

If you really want to do the loop by yourself, consider getting the row pointer to the data directly `mat.data`, or `mat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>`.

If you want to speed up the task of computing mean/stdDev on any part of your image, then use [integral images](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=integral#integral). The doc is pretty clear about it, and I'm pretty sure it will take less than 2.5s probably even in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check it all tomorrow and will get back with results.

Comment: @JeniaM So, any luck yet?

Comment: Heh, yeah sry forgot to write the results.
Yeah the debug mode was the key. Dropped the execution by like 10 times on the spot. 
In the end did some modifications in the approach at all and the result was achieved in 0.3 sec :)
Tnx a lot for the help